# How to find and remove unwanted processes in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, system-administration

Is there any way to programmatically find out what processes and apps came with the installed os?

Is there any way to programmatically find out what processes that one has installed?

Is there any way to programmatically find out which process belongs to which app?

Is there is a way programmatically search through the signature and security information in the task manager or resource monitor?

Answer (score 0):

in the run command wirte , msconfig and go to the startup to see the programs that processing

Comment: yes, you can see the startup, but that takes you to the task manager (on 8.1), the services tab does contain some of the info that i want. but how to get at it programmatically and how to know if the manufacturer is correct?